# I'm trying to return details of an array, but I am returning zeros instead

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, output

I'm just looking for assistance because I can't seem to figure out why my program is printing out zeros rather than what is being requested.

Using Eclipse, I am reading a text file entailing integers into an array and then outputting its integers in ascending order, the product of all integers in the array, and the arrays min and max values. The array prints fine as well as the sorting. I've also attached a photo to the end of this post of the output when I actually run the program for clarification. Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Also, this is my first post on this forum so I would appreciate any help to post properly. Thanks, you guys.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;//imports scanner class

public class Project1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception   
    {   
        int i=0,j;
        int[]numbers=new int[20];
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File("number.txt"));
        BigInteger product=getMultiplication(numbers);
        int minimum=getMinValue(numbers);
        int maximum=getMaxValue(numbers);
        

            while(inputFile.hasNext()) 
            {
                numbers[i++]=Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine());
            }
            
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
            
            System.out.println("Numbers in ascending order:");
            Arrays.sort(numbers);
            System.out.println(""+Arrays.toString(numbers));
            System.out.println(" ");
            
            System.out.println("The product of the numbers in the array is: ");
            System.out.println(""+product);
            
            System.out.println("The minimum value of the array is: ");
            System.out.println(""+minimum);
            
            System.out.println("The maximum value of the array is: ");
            System.out.println(""+maximum);
            
            inputFile.close();
    }

    private static int getMaxValue(int[] numbers) {
        int maximum=numbers[0];
        for(int i:numbers)
        {
            if (maximum<i)
                maximum=i;
        }
        return maximum;
    }

    private static int getMinValue(int[] numbers) {
        int minimum=numbers[0];
        for(int i:numbers)
        {
            if (minimum>i)
                minimum=i;
        }
        return minimum;
    }

    private static BigInteger getMultiplication(int[] numbers) {
        BigInteger j=new BigInteger("1");
        for (int i:numbers)
        {
            j=j.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        return j;
    }   
}
```

[program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN4Kd.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
BigInteger product=getMultiplication(numbers);
int minimum=getMinValue(numbers);
int maximum=getMaxValue(numbers);
        
while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
     numbers[i++]=Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine());
}
```

Change it to this so you call the methods after you enter the numbers.

```
while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
     numbers[i++]=Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine());
}

BigInteger product=getMultiplication(numbers);
int minimum=getMinValue(numbers);
int maximum=getMaxValue(numbers);
```

Comment: Yep, can't use the values in the array before putting them in the array